# CakePHP and AJAX to update Database without page refresh

Tags: database, ajax, cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP 1.3.7 and I'm trying to do the following:

On a given page, the user can click a link (or image, or button, doesn't matter) that passes a parameter which is saved into a database. BUT, all this, **without refreshing the page**.

I've been doing some research and I believe I need to use AJAX as well to acomplish this. However, I can't find the a good example/explanation on how to do it.

I think that the idea is to create the link using AJAX, which calls the controller/action that would receive the variable as a parameter and performs the operation to save it in its corresponding field/table of the DB.

Does anyone have a small example of what I want to do? Or maybe point me to some tutorial that explains it... Thanks so much in advance!

**EDIT**

Well, thank you guys for your replies. THey're not working directly, but I think I'm getting closer to what I want. Here's what i'm doing now:

I have this code in my view:

```
<div id="prev"><a>click me</a></div>

<div id="message_board"> </div>
```

I call this JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#prev").click(function(event) {      
    $.ajax({data:{name:"John",id:"100"}, dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#message_board").html(data);}, type:"post", url:"\/galleries\/add"});
    return false;
});
});
```

And my **add** action in my **galleries** controller looks like:

```
function add() {

    $this->autoRender = false;  

    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {

    echo "<h2>Hello</h2>";
    print_r($this->data);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';

        if(!empty($this->data)) {

    $fields = array('phone' => 8, 'modified' => false);
        $this->User->id = 6;
            $this->User->save($fields, false, array('phone'));

        }
}
}
```

When clicking on the '#prev' element, I get a response from the **add** action, I know because the text 'Hello' is printed inside **#message_board**. And it does this without refreshing the page, which is why I need. My problem is that I can't make the **$.ajax()** function to send any data, when it gets to the controller the **$this->data** is empty, so it never goes inside the **if** that saves the info to the database (right now it's saving just an easy thing, but I will want it to save the data that comes from the view).

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong? How can I send the data to the controller?

Comment: Corrected and clarified the answer.

Comment: Albert 

print_r($_REQUEST); 

And you may find your answer!

Comment: I tried this and you're right, I can find the data sent there. It's just that I thought that $this->data would hold all the POST data, but as Amadan has explained below, it just works when data is submited via form. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP does not matter, most of the code you would need for this would be at clientside. Implementing AJAX by yourself is a pain in the $, so you really want to use a library; currently the most popular is probably jQuery. There's a bunch of examples on their AJAX page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So, assuming you have something like this in the document:

```
<form id="s">
  <input id="q"/>
  <input type="submit" href="Search!"/>
</form>
<div id="r"/>
```

you can put this in the JavaScript:

```
$('#s').submit(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    data: {
        query: $('#q').val()
      },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#r').html(data);
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Then your `foo.php` only needs to return the fragment HTML that would go into the `div#r`.

EDIT: I forgot to stop the submit :( Thanks to @Leo for the correction.

EDIT: I can see what your confusion is about. You will not get a `data`. I haven't worked with CakePHP, but I assume `$this->data` is what you'd get from `$_REQUEST['data']`? You don't get that on the server. `data` is a hash of what is getting submitted; you will directly get the `$_REQUEST['name']` and `$_REQUEST['id']` (which, I assume, translate into CakePHP as `$this->name` and `$this->id`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I really need to know, though, is if I can call a controller/action from a view to perform whatever code it has, without leaving (or refreshing) the current page.

Comment: And what about without using a form? Would this be possible? I mean, clicking just a link...

Comment: then use $('some-selector').click(function(){...}) instead of submit. You have to read more about jQuery...

Comment: Sorry, this is not working for me... I do have read about jQuery, but when I have to mix it with my CakePHP web I can't make it work in this case.

Comment: **$this->data** is an array with the variables you send to the server, I'm not so sure about the exact format. I believe that to access those variables it would be something like **data['name']** and **data['id']**. Anyways, regardless of the format, when doing **empty($this->data)** in the **add()** function, it should not be true (well, if I was doing this correctly, of course). Maybe i need to use dome other **dataType** or something, because doing **$_REQUEST['variable']** it's not what you're supposed to do in CakePHP, I believe.

Comment: In the following example: [link](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/cakephp-ajax-quick-save-jquery), the guy receives the data using **$this->data**, the problem is that he sends it using a form and **ajaxSubmit** (and something else, but I don't understand all of that code), but that's not what I need. I'm pretty sure it's possible to do what I want, I just can't figure out how. Although I really appreciate your guys dedication to help!

Comment: See the description of `$this->data` and notice how it's a special case (triggered by a special `name` of the submitting parameter), which is where parameters end up when you use FormHelper. http://book.cakephp.org/view/972/data#!/view/963/The-Parameters-Attribute-params . If you don't use FormHelper (as I don't, not being CakePHP dev :) but you might want to), the stuff apparently ends up in $this->params['form']. Or you might modify the JS bit, send no `data`, and say `url: "gallery/add/" + id + "/" + name`, and pick up on the values by the normal controller routing. Remember to escape. :)

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing this last night and it worked! I had not realized that $this->data was just for form submissions, I thought it held all the POST data, but obviously I was wrong. Thank you very much for your help, now I understand all this stuff a little better :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
$('#s').submit(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
```

To prevent a page refresh, as in Amadans answer just refer to your controller/ action in the url variable

```
$('#s').submit(function(evt) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/patients/search/',
    data: {
        query: $('#q').val()
      },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#r').html(data);
      }
```

In the patients/add controller action make sure you return a valid result ( in json is good )

Comment: I just edited my question with new info, I'm trying to do what you have here, but without a form. Could you take a look to it and see what am I doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: D'oh! Forgot the important step! Indeed, you are correct. I'll ninja it in, for completeness sake...